# Creating a backup of a website directory inside the Web Application Root directory in *nix

Tags: security, bash, linux

In CentOS I have a Web Application Root on which I have a website directory.
I would like to make an immediate backup of that website's directory by using the `zip` utility. The code works and tested.

Although I already use `set -x` and zipping is verbose (I'm not sure if due to `set -x` or `zip` default behavior), the trace is super long and hard to follow - I cant vertically-scroll all of the way top of it through Putty Window in Windows10 Home.
I fear I don't have enough testing to ensure that the file was created, in what size (to assume the size is plausible) and such (maybe just adding `ls -la ${war}/mediawiki_general_backups`, is enough):

```
date="$(date +%F-%T)"
war="$HOME/public_html" # Web Application Root
domain="example.com"
zip -r "${war}/mediawiki_general_backups/${domain}-directory-backup-${date}.zip" "${war}/${domain}"
```

Comment: Theorizing on reasons/s for dislike would be extremely helpful

Comment: I didn't DV the question, but I suspect it's because the second-to-last paragraph reads like you're not _entirely_ sure if it works. That said, I see no functional discrepancies that would prevent it from working.

Comment: And I only make that assumption because there's also a close-vote on the question for "Broken", though I don't see the legitimacy of that either.

Comment: The code works in tested before. Please consider edit the question because I am not sure I understand what's wrong...

Comment: I would recommend that you edit your question to make it clearer it works. When your write *"Hence, I fear I might need a tiny bit more "testing" to see..."* that kind of makes it unclear if your code works.

Comment: Okay, thank you --- just edited.

Comment: Why are you using `set -x`? (that will expand each simple command in your script and display the output of each) That will make for very long output.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I use it in default because it is convenient for me; usually it does more good than harm in my work.

Comment: Sure, `set -x` is a great debugging tool. I comment was prompted by the vertical scrolling problem mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend starting the script with a shebang so it can be executed as a program:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

As there's nothing in here that isn't standard shell, then we can make it leaner by using plain POSIX shell instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

I recommend `set -eu`, to cause the shell to abort in more error cases.

We can save one fork by using `exec` for the final command.  In either case, the exit status should indicate whether the command completed successfully (if running from `cron`, consider using `chronic` when running the script, to only be mailed about the failures).

I question the use of `zip` as archive format - `tar` is generally installed on all Linux systems, and is the nearest we have to a standard.  `zip` usually needs to be specifically added.  Also, `tar` supports the `-C` option so that we can store relative paths in the archive, which may be useful if this backup is restored onto a new system with different file layout.

And whilst your quoting is good, it's slightly over the top - variable assignment is implicitly double-quoted.

```
#!/bin/sh

date=$(date +%F-%T)
war=$HOME/public_html # Web Application Root
domain=example.com
archive=mediawiki_general_backups/$domain-directory-backup-$date.tar.gz

exec tar -C "$war" cfz "$archive" "$domain"
```

Finally, are you sure that's a good place to keep your backups?  If the disk fails and you lose the site contents, you've probably lost the backups as well.  I hope that this is only the first stage in making your backups and that you have a mechanism to transfer the archive files to offline media (preferably off-site) that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Hi; thanks. I do have an external automatic backup system; AFAIK this entire shared server is backedup externally with daily backups for each user going 30 days backwards.

Comment: I misunderstand this passage: `And whilst your quoting is good, it's slightly over the top - variable assignment is implicitly double-quoted.`; everything is double quoted both in my example and yours... What did you mean than?

Comment: What I mean is that `a="$b"` can be written as just `a=$b` because word splitting and globbing don't occur in the context of variable assignment.  It's not *wrong* to write the former, so if you like the consistency, just keep doing what you're doing!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be honest I am not exactly sure what do you want to review :) This isn't a script. It is just standard zip command.

Maybe you should think about this: `${war}/mediawiki_general_backups/${domain}-directory-backup-${date}.zip`. It is too long and ugly. Try to add more these things into your script and a readability will be lost.

> I fear I don't have enough testing to ensure that the file was created,

If you want to be sure, that the zip command finished sucessfully, just test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately.
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/2871034/10814755
# Now i should trust the output of zip command. 
set -e

#domain=$1 <- It could be useful, isn't?
domain="example.com"

#I omit application root. I thing is safer to keep backups away.
backup_path="/mediawiki_backups/${domain}/"
backup_file="$(date +%F-%T).zip"

# You should trust the zip command, but sure is sure.
# So if backup file exist...
# ...and isn't empty...
if [[ -f ${backup_path}${backup_file} ]] && [[ ! -s ${backup_path}${backup_file} ]]; then
  #... then do something brave :)
else
  echo "Backup failed!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Regards :)